# Linkify custom location in textView?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, textview, android-intent

I have a TextView with location data that I want to Linkify. When link will be clicked an Intent should be fired that will start Maps. How should I achieve this effect?

UPDATE:

I have something like "My street 9, My city". Now I want to have all this text to appear like a link and have intent fired with URI: `geo:0,0?q=My+street+9,+My+city`

Using just `Linkify.ALL` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set attribute android:autoLink = "all" on your textView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:autoLink